# how to view pdf file in tiny box in jsp

Tags: java, jsp-tags

i want view pdf file in tiny box in jsp with out any option like download,view.please give java source example

```
File f= new File(file);
if(f.exists()){
ServletOutputStream op= response.getOutputStream();
response.reset();
if(check==1){
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
}else{
response.setContentType(content);
          }
// response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=" +fileName);
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
int length;
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(buf)) != -1)){
op.write(buf,0,length);
                }
in.close();
op.flush();
op.close();
}

and already i done download pdf file use this code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com/markup/). This would need Javascript. You can also use `Object` tag as follows

```
<object data="yourfile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
  <p>Alternative text - include a link <a href="yourfile.pdf">yourfile</a></p>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this one.am not sure about it.but you can try it.

```
 TINY.box.show({url: "your url", post: "mainid=" + varMainId + "&subid=" + yourID);
```